# Making a network-visible dlna renderer

Tags: 14.04, networking, dlna

I need a type of DLNA renderer software on my computer that allows access by UPnP AV-Controllers on the local network.

It shall function like most TVs do, so I can let it run unattended and start videos on it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But...  I've now read your question 3 times, and I still don't understand...  Are you looking for DLNA client software for a PC?

Comment: @Fabby sorry to confuse you. Basically I want to install the type of DLNA software that is usually found on TVs on my Ubuntu computer. I'm gonna clean up my question a fair bit as well.

Comment: OK, that's what I have with minidlna...  But you said you had that too.  Do you need any configuration help???

Answer (score 2):

Totem should support this with the right plugins installed. See this blog post http://blog.andresgomez.org/2012/09/05/nslu2-grilo-and-upnp-in-ubuntus-gnome/

It may still be true that the totem is not build with the grilo plugin in trusty.

I was able to get grilo plugin in rhythmbox by starting rhythmbox and enabling it. Go to Tools->Plugins and check the box next to Grilo media browser.

Alternately:

You can install Rygel from Ubuntu Software Center. It supports both UPnP AV MediaServer as well as becoming a MediaRenderer.

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Rygel